# Cassandra UUID Query Problems

Tags: java, cassandra

Is the following possible in Cassandra? I'd like to get a list of all UUIDs from a table, but I keep getting errors. Here is the code in question:

```
@Query("SELECT id FROM table")
public Result<UUID> getIds();
```

And here are the errors:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error preparing queries for accessor DeviceAccessor
    at com.datastax.driver.mapping.AccessorMapper.prepare(AccessorMapper.java:48)
    at com.datastax.driver.mapping.MappingManager.getAccessor(MappingManager.java:156)
    at com.datastax.driver.mapping.MappingManager.createAccessor(MappingManager.java:109)
    at com.tmp.whatever.persistence.DevicePersistenceHandler.init(DevicePersistenceHandler.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:133)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot map return to class class com.datastax.driver.mapping.Result
    at com.datastax.driver.mapping.MethodMapper.mapType(MethodMapper.java:118)
    at com.datastax.driver.mapping.MethodMapper.prepare(MethodMapper.java:93)
    at com.datastax.driver.mapping.AccessorMapper.prepare(AccessorMapper.java:46)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @Table annotation was not found on type java.util.UUID
    at com.datastax.driver.mapping.AnnotationParser.getTypeAnnotation(AnnotationParser.java:292)
    at com.datastax.driver.mapping.AnnotationParser.parseEntity(AnnotationParser.java:49)
    at com.datastax.driver.mapping.MappingManager.getMapper(MappingManager.java:119)
    at com.datastax.driver.mapping.MappingManager.mapper(MappingManager.java:76)
    at com.datastax.driver.mapping.MethodMapper.mapType(MethodMapper.java:116)
    ... 53 more
```

I am fairly new to Cassandra and this is my first attempt at a query without any training wheels, so there is a chance I missed something obvious. The Result class is from com.datastax.driver.mapping if it helps.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS devices (
  id uuid,
  name text,
  description text,
  device_type text,
  address text,
  port int,
  ssl boolean,
  credentials uuid,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Comment: That depends.  Can you post the structure (schema) of your table?

Answer (score 0):

The methods in Datastax's Acessor interface can either return void or an instance of the class(or Result

Comment: So this means that it cannot return individual fields from the table?

Comment: Not by using accessors. You can execute a query directly or via query builder and get your columns from the result set.